# Writing into the last byte of a class

Tags: c++, c++11

Given a standard layout class with standard layout members such as:

```
struct foo {
    int n;
    int m;
    unsigned char garbage;
};
```

will it always be safe, according to the standard, to write in the last byte of the struct without writing into the memory areas of `n` and `m` (but possibly writing into `garbage`)? E.g.,

```
foo f;
*(static_cast<unsigned char *>(static_cast<void *>(&f)) + (sizeof(foo) - 1u)) = 0u;
```

After spending some time reading the C++11 standard, it seems to me like the answer might be yes.

From 9.2/15:

> Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class with the same access control (Clause 11) are allocated so
>   that later members have higher addresses within a class object. The order of allocation of non-static data
>   members with different access control is unspecified (11). Implementation alignment requirements might
>   cause two adjacent members not to be allocated immediately after each other; so might requirements for
>   space for managing virtual functions (10.3) and virtual base classes (10.1).

Hence, the `garbage` member has a higher address than the other two members (which are stored contiguously themselves as they have standard layout), and the last byte of the struct must hence either belong to `garbage` or be part of the final padding.

Is this reasoning correct? Am I meddling with the `f` object lifetime here? Is writing into padding bytes a problem?

**EDIT**

In reply to the comments, what I am trying to achieve here has to do with a variant-like class I am writing.

If proceed in a straightforward way (i.e., place an int member in the variant class to record which type is being stored), the padding will make the class almost 50% bigger than it needs to be.

What I am trying to do is to make sure that every last byte of each class type I am going to store in the variant is writable, so I can incorporate the storage flag into the raw storage (aligned raw char array) I am using in the variant. In my specific case, this eliminates most of the wasted space.

**EDIT 2**

As an actual example, consider these two classes to be stored in a variant on a typical 64-bit machine:

```
// Small dynamic vector class storing 8-bit integers.
class first {
    std::int8_t    *m_ptr;
    unsigned short m_size_capacity; // Size and capacity packed into a single ushort.
};

// Vector class with static storage.
class second {
    std::int8_t  m_data[15];
    std::uint8_t m_size;
};

class variant
{
    char m_data[...] // Properly sized and aligned for first and second.
    bool m_flag; // Flag to signal which class is being stored.
};
```

The size of these two classes is 16 on my machine, the extra member needed in the variant class makes the size go to 24. If I now add the garbage byte in the end:

```
// Small dynamic vector class storing 8-bit integers.
class first {
    std::int8_t    *m_ptr;
    unsigned short m_size_capacity; // Size and capacity packed into a single ushort.
    unsigned char  m_garbage;
};

// Vector class with static storage.
class second {
    std::int8_t    m_data[14]; // Note I lost a vector element here.
    std::uint8_t   m_size;
    unsigned char  m_garbage;
};
```

The size of both classes will still be 16, but if now I can use the last byte of each class freely I can do away with the flag member in the variant, and the final size will still be 16.

Comment: You are right I think.. but that does look ugly..

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Why are you asking this question? In what situation would you want to perform a write that doesn't go into a definite member of the struct?

Comment: As I read it, there is no guarantee that your single char will occupy the *last* byte of the *defined* structure. As you pointed out, you can easily be writing into padding. Would you be overwriting `n` or `m`? No; of that I think you're quite-correct.

Comment: Why on Earth are you writing code that is difficult (at best) to read? Got a problem with job security?

Comment: would *(static_cast<unsigned char *>(static_cast<void *>((&f) + 1) - 1)) = 0u; be a little bit cleaner?  As for padding bytes, I have seen over and over how padding bytes that are being written into are not a problem until compiler changes which suddenly changes padding bytes however with this you are not really depending on padding bytes but rather attempting to use the last byte of the struct instead.

Comment: I added some explanatory comments in the original post. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: @RichardChambers: good point about readability. Yes, the point would not be to be depending on padding bytes, I just want to make sure that writing into the last byte of the struct won't mess up `n` and `m`.

Comment: if you are concerned about padding, does your compiler have a pragma to reduce padding so that for instance it will provide single byte boundary rather than 4 byte boundary?

Comment: @RichardChambers: I have considered that, but I was trying to understand (also for my own interest) if a solution can be achieved in a standard-compliant way. I am going to investigate it though, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @RichardChambers: The problem with those pragmas is that they destroy alignment.

Comment: Why are you worrying about a few bytes? My phone has a small chip in it that holds 32Gb. Cost £20

Comment: @EdHeal: if you have a memory-bound algorithm, reducing memory usage can mean increasing runtime performance correspondingly.

Comment: @EdHeal: If you don't know the difference between cache, RAM, and disk, perhaps you should stay away from performance questions.

Comment: I do know the difference. CPU like to grab memory in handy chunks. aka alignment. Also trying to micro-optimise always leads into taking your eye off the ball.

Comment: @EdHeal: Then why did you comment about the NAND flash disk in your phone, if you know it's 100 times too slow to be relevant to this question?

Comment: @BenVoigt - Because memory is cheap. Your time is not. Why worry about a few bytes here or there when you can find out where the performance hit is better to be tackled. i.e. gather some evidence

Comment: @EdHeal: The memory that counts is not cheap.  How much does it cost to add RAM to your phone?  Oh wait, you can't, you have to throw the whole thing away and buy one designed with more RAM from the beginning.  How much does it cost to double the size of your L1 cache?

Comment: @BenVoigt - Get real - We are talking about a few bytes. BTW - Went to a store and paid £20 for a 32Gb - inserted into my phone. Also bought 4Gb of memory for my PC. £40 - see http://www.amazon.co.uk/Memory-Dell-Latitude-E6520-DDR3-10600/dp/B009256G02/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1378089916&sr=8-7&keywords=dell+ram

Comment: @EdHeal: Obviously, you DON'T understand the difference between NAND flash disks, RAM, and L1 cache.  Or else you are trolling.  BTW, it's probably "a few bytes" multiplied by a dataset with 20 million entries.

Comment: @BenVoigt - Shifting data from/to memory the CPU does like and performs better when it is aligned - i.e. The processor does not care about having to grab those extra few bytes. It is call alignment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead, you should put the tag *first*, followed by the other small members.

```
// Small dynamic vector class storing 8-bit integers.
struct first
{
    unsigned char  m_tag;
    std::uint8_t   m_size;
    std::uint8_t   m_capacity;
    std::int8_t    *m_ptr;
};

// Vector class with static storage.
struct second
{
    unsigned char  m_tag;
    std::uint8_t   m_size;
    std::int8_t    m_data[14];
};
```

Then, the language rules allow you to put these into a `union` and use either one to access `m_tag`, even if that wasn't the "active" member of the union, because the initial layout is the same (special rule for common initial sequence of members).

```
union tight_vector
{
     first dynamic;
     second small_opt;
};

tight_vector v;
if (v.dynamic.m_size < 4) throw std::exception("Not enough data");
if (v.dynamic.m_tag == DYNAMIC) { /* use v.dynamic */ }
else { /* use v.small_opt */ }
```

---

The rule in question is 9.2/18:

> If a standard-layout union contains two or more standard-layout structs that share a common initial sequence, and if the standard-layout union object currently contains one of these standard-layout structs, it is permitted to inspect the common initial part of any of them. Two standard-layout structs share a common initial sequence if corresponding members have layout-compatible types and either neither member is a bit-field or both are bit-fields with the same width for a sequence of one or more initial members.

Comment: Oh wow, that looks much better. Would you be able to point me in the (general) direction of that special rule in the standard? Got some reading to do :) Cheers!

Comment: +1, this is the intended purpose of the standard layout idea.

Comment: C++ feature idea: Make it so you can use the syntax `v.m_size` instead of `v.dynamic.m_size` for prefix members of union members that have this layout requirement and the same member name across all union members. :)

Comment: @user1131467: This is totally the wrong place for C++ feature suggestions.  Really, I wouldn't want that done automatically (which name would it pick?, the rule does NOT require the names to match), but `using m_size = v.dynamic.m_size;` would be awesome.

Comment: @BenVoigt: As I said, it would only do the implicit using when the member names are the same, have the same type, and are part of the layout prefix members that 9.2/18 applies to. :)

Comment: @user1131467: That could cause accidental matches. But if you restrict it to members of a shared base class, that would be virtually impossible. I.e. allow it only if `v.dynamic.size` and `v.small_opt.size` both refer to `UnionBase::size`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in C++ any object, including a class, is represented as a series of addressable `char` objects ("bytes"), and objects declared in sequence in a class without intervening access specifiers have sequentially ascending addresses. Therefore storage for `garbage` must have a higher address (when addressed as `char *`) than `n` or `m`.

In theory the compiler could store a base class at the end of the object, or something like a vtable pointer, but in practice such things always go into the beginning for the sake of simplicity. I'm not sure what the standard guarantees about the size of a standard-layout class, which would pertain to whether padding may be added, which would have implications for whether an implementation could rely on presence of padding for some purpose, but it probably comes down to the implementation being allowed to use padding which happens to be there, but it can't add any (and access would perhaps not be simple or efficient anyway).

> What I am trying to do is to make sure that every last byte of each class type I am going to store in the variant is writable

How is this different from using the `garbage` member itself? If you know it's there, presumably you can simply access it.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have added an example in the OP. Essentially, the m_garbage member will be in different offsets depending on which class is being stored in the variant.

Comment: @bluescarni Is this just an exercise or is there actually an advantage here over e.g. `boost::variant`?

Comment: partly an excercise, but I can get real benefits by shaving off some bytes (memory bound algorithm for some sparse computer algebra algorithm).

Comment: Something practical an implementation might do with those padding bytes would be to write a canary value and later assert it is unchanged, to help catch buffer overrun bugs (especially since they're so commonly associated with security vulnerabilities).

Comment: @BenVoigt Could do, but in practice the memory analyzer is more likely to be too far separated from the part of the compiler which understands the `struct` definitions for that to be practicable.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: For POD types it would be difficult, because they have trivial construction and there's no chance to store the canary.  For types with constructor and destructor, though, the compiler could transparently insert the security checks there.

Comment: @user1131467 To be sure, the original proposal is noncompliant. The premise is that two objects are going to live in the same place, which is forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

The last byte of the struct will not be part of n and m, but how do you know the compiler hasn't stored something else in the last byte, such as type information?

I don't recall the standard guaranteeing any such thing.  Only that a memcpy of sizeof(T) into and out will result in the same value, which doesn't mean that the final byte doesn't hold information.

Comment: Mhmmm, I was thinking the compatibility requirements with C structs would prevent this, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @bluescarni: I think it is potentially UB.  You are assigning a value `0u` of type `unsigned char` to an object that may not be `unsigned char` (in the event `garbage` is not the last byte of `foo`).  In fact it may not be an object at all.